# Convert desired output xml to json

Tags: dataweave

Below XML key names should be converted into uppercase() and apply a short-end method without multiple map object loops. Output as a JSON object.
Input:

```
<employees>
 <employee>
   <id>
     <name>Mohan</name>
     <dept>Admin</dept>
   </id>
   <id>
     <name>ravi</name>
     <dept>Network</dept>
   </id>
  </employee>
</employees>

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Explain why 'multiple map object loops' are not to be used and please provide expected output sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a method to `upper` the keys of an Object and call it recursively.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json duplicateKeyAsArray = true 
fun upperKeys(obj: Object) = 
    obj mapObject ((value, key) -> 
            (upper(key as String)): value match {
                case is Object -> upperKeys(value)
                else -> value
            }
    )
---
upperKeys(payload)
```

Since you are dealing with XML you do not need to handle an Array otherwise you can add one more case if you want to extend this function to work for JSON as well.

Now because you need the output as JSON you will need to consider how you want to handle duplicate keys for XML. I have used `output application/json duplicateKeyAsArray = true`  just as an example but use it with caution.

Comment: One observation, output should be JSON.